# on edit trigger for sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

ive read so many pages im just confusing myself more. i appologize if this has already been answered. I want to autorun a script for sendEmail. OnEdit seems like the best way to go. Another answerr page said open Resources in script page and add installable onedit trigger and i dont have those options.

This is my data sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JNR3P0y0d2N3WmDD6esTCsmbR0pZlep8XJ20Fgk7weM/edit?usp=sharing

Tgis is my SendEmail sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M3VNTWnTdg-kaaO8fJC0Hgl7eB59nj9DWNhcBlqvx8g/edit?usp=sharing

This is my script

```
    function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1)
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();  
      for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];  
        var emailAddress = row[0];    // First column
        var message = row[1];         // Second column
        var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";  
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
      }
```

}

https://script.google.com/macros/d/M-cbS9PoBLtOiPcyO2hCERCbSOeAB_zAy/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvHW9psxJ-EbLRiDsVIgaE0q1d61233msqITBKHz_i-A9kCyaGGj4qokdLwR10_eDAyQa7aCPDwM5DCnjgN9r8-5i_KehepDcIF5tCEfJQlXLDWURB5KvZ7A9rIQ2PWFxw7ZV_SHugE

I just wnt it to email me the value from B2 of the sendEmail sheet once it has a value. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Matt - Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, can you help to write your post with the code you are having problems with inline? Can you also make sure your links are accessible?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JNR3P0y0d2N3WmDD6esTCsmbR0pZlep8XJ20Fgk7weM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What problem are you having? Did you place the sendEmails() function inside the onEdit() trigger so that any changes (not only B2) to the 'sendEmail sheet' will send an email to you?

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/):

They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.